# Is California a year-round destination?

Tags: california

I'm thinking of taking three weeks to visit California and I'm hoping to catch some sun (I live in Scotland - sun on holiday is a must!).

If I choose to visit California at the end of January, beginning of February, is there a chance it will be cold (10C/50F)and/or rainy?

I know California is a big place, but I am looking forward to soaking up the sun.

Comment: It really does depend on where you want to go.  In the mountains, it's ski season at that time of year.

Comment: Will you be able to move around, or will you commit in advance to a particular place in California? Any given area of California could be the target of a [pineapple express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple_Express) weather pattern for most of an arbitrary three week period.

Comment: In late January/early Feb, the farther south you go in California the more likely you are to have good weather. This is not at all a guarantee, though.

Comment: You might want to see this http://www.holiday-weather.com/los_angeles/averages/january/. Average seems to be 13C with considerable rainfall.

Comment: I will have a car so I will be able to move around. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: California is ENORMOUS.  England and Scotland would fit inside its footprint..   Glasgow/Edinburgh = San Francisco/Sacramento.   Brighton/Dover = San Diego/Palm Springs.   It's like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**YES**.  California as a whole is a year round destination.  For the best chance of sun stay south.

Look into Palm Springs.  Warning though, it will likely be sunny but cool or even *cold*. Average high in January is between 67-70F (18-21C) (From a Wyndham Resorts/[Vacation Palm Springs](https://vacationpalmsprings.com/palm-springs-weather-info-by-month-season-highlights-palmspringsca.php) website).

If you want ocean with your sun, the water temperature in La Jolla (north of San Diego) will be around 55-63F / 15-17C. Gathered from Google searches, but here's a [temperature table](https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/dsdt/cwtg/spac.html) for various southern California beaches from NOAA.

Comment: For someone from Scotland, 18–21°C would probably be considered warm, not cool. :)

Comment: @gsnedders, true =0)